# Connect three monitors to the same workstation

Tags: hardware, multiple-monitors

I have an **Nvidia Quadro 600** card in my workstation and was curious if there was any way I could use three monitors with the card without using external graphics hardware (Matrox display2go et al.). It has 1 Dual Link DVI-I port and 1 DisplayPort port. I'm using two monitors, one with each port but I would like to have a third one.

Is that possible somehow?

Thanks

Comment: zero programming content.

Comment: I'll bet you can, but it doesn't require any programming on your part so it's off-topic here.

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn'n know that forum was only for software questions. Actually the `hadware` topic is in one of the multiple displayed when you created the post

Comment: [tag:hardware] - "**Programming** questions related to the physical components of a computer."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to connect the third monitor: [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-External-Video-Monitor-Adapter/dp/B0086359SG/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1388206061&sr=1-2&keywords=usb+3.0+to+dvi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0086359SG)

I have plenty of USB 3.0 so that is the best option.

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can. I have seen some **thin client concept** which connects through an ethernet cord. Monitor gets a power adapter, just like for mobile. I have seen this setup with a **D-link manufacturer.**. But it in fact works for any machine.